# Getting Payments Alert from Stripe without Webhook

Tags: stripe-payments

The default way for third party clients to be notified when a payment has happened on stripe is mostly via Webhooks. However, I do not want to stress my users by giving them a webhook url to paste in their stripe dashboard to be notified when payment has happened. I want to simplify the process for them. Is there an alternative flow?

I'm looking at something similar to `Sign In With Google` once they authenticate the app against their stripe dashboard, payment alerts can be seemlessly retrieved.

Going through the Stripe connect Docs and I'm not sure Connect can be used to achieve this. I stand to be corrected though.

I need to implement this in NodeJS.

Any insights would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you're operating as a platform and want to send some message to your users (who are Stripe account holders) to notify about payments.

You can do this using [Connect webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks#connect-webhooks) to listen for payments on those connected accounts, eg by listening for `payment_intent.succeeded` or what is relevant for your integration.

You, as the platform, would set up a webhook to listen for these events, then you can use whatever communication channels you prefer with your users to notify them (eg: email, SMS, in-app notification etc)